# not copying protections of one sheet to the duplicated sheet google sheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am working on google sheets. I coded in javascript in SCRIPT EDITOR.
I have a sheet (IKASLEA (student) that is duplicated everytime I write a name on IKASLE ZERRENDA (stutents name) sheet.
Until here everything is okay.
But the protections that IKASLEA sheet has are not copied to the duplicated ones...
It seems that there is a timeout of 30 seconds...
I have tried everything and nothing works ...
If you could give me a hand I would very much appreciate it! :)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kPN0SFi0DWydlYEJlbn6SNZ_1-8q2uaxLtS46T1GzVs/edit?usp=sharing

I need to copy properly the protections. All of them. That IKASLEA sheet has.

Comment: - [Welcome to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) Please provide a [mcve] so that we can see the code that you are using to create the problem.  Please post it into you question.- [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: `1)` As noted by @Cooper  please edit the question to include the relevant script **in the body of the question**; please don't expect that users must open the spreadsheet to understand the question. `2)` Users don't know what triggers you have created, please edit the question to include this information. `3) But the protections that IKASLEA sheet has are not copied to the duplicated ones`. This does not seem to be the case - please edit the question to be more specific about the expected outcome. `4) It seems that there is a timeout of 30 seconds` Please explain the relevance of this remark.

Answer (score 0):

This is my full code: The function where duplicated the protections is :duplicateSheetProtections

```
const MAIN_SHEET = 'IKASLE ZERRENDA';
const BASE_SHEET = 'IKASLEA';

const SHEETS_TO_OMIT = [
  MAIN_SHEET, BASE_SHEET
]

const filterSheets = (sheetName) => !SHEETS_TO_OMIT.includes(sheetName) && !sheetName?.startsWith('DBH')

const listSheets = () => {
 const spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

 return spreadSheet.getSheets().map((ss)=> ss.getName())
}

const removeAllUnusedSheets =() => {
  const spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const sheetList = listSheets()
  const sheetsToRemove = getSheetsToRemove(sheetList)

  try {
  sheetsToRemove.forEach((sheetName) => spreadSheet.deleteSheet(spreadSheet.getSheetByName(sheetName)))
  } catch(error) {
    console.error('Error on removeAllUnusedSheets', error)
  }
  return; 
}

const getStudentsList = () => {
  const spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const sheetList = listSheets()
  const sheetActive =  spreadSheet.getActiveSheet()
  try {
    return sheetActive.getSheetValues(2,1,-1,1).map((student) => student[0]?.trim()).filter(s => s.length > 0)
  } catch(_) {
    return [];
  }
}

const getSheetsToRemove = (sheetList) => {
  const spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheetActive =  spreadSheet.getActiveSheet()

  try {
    const students = sheetActive.getSheetValues(2,1,-1,1).map((student) => student[0]);

    return sheetList.filter((sheetName) => !students.includes(sheetName) && filterSheets(sheetName))
  } catch(_) {
    return sheetList.filter(filterSheets)
  }
}

const sortSheets = () => {
  const spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

  const students = getStudentsList();

  students.forEach((student, index) => {
    if(student) {
      const studentSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName(student);
      spreadSheet.setActiveSheet(studentSheet)
      spreadSheet.moveActiveSheet(index+3)
    }
  }) 

  spreadSheet.setActiveSheet(spreadSheet.getSheetByName(MAIN_SHEET))
}

const copySheet = (studentName) => {
  const spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const sheetToCopy = spreadSheet.getSheetByName(BASE_SHEET)

  const newSheet = sheetToCopy.copyTo(spreadSheet);
  newSheet.setName(studentName.trim())
}


const handleStudents = () => {
  removeAllUnusedSheets();
  const students = getStudentsList();

  students.forEach(handleStudent);

  sortSheets();
}

const handleStudent = (studentName)  => {
  try {
    copySheet(studentName);
    duplicateSheetProtections(studentName);
  } catch(_) {}
  // duplicateSheetProtections(studentName);
}

const onChange = (event) => {
  console.log(event)
}

const oli = () => console.log('FROM DISPATCH')

const duplicateSheetProtections = (sheetName) => {
  try {
    const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 

    // Obtener la hoja base y la hoja duplicada
    const baseSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(BASE_SHEET); 
    const duplicatedSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);

    // Eliminar protecciones existentes en la hoja duplicada
    const existingProtections = duplicatedSheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
    existingProtections.forEach(existingProtection => existingProtection.remove());

    // Obtener protecciones de la hoja base
    const protections = baseSheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);

    // Duplicar protecciones a la hoja duplicada
    protections.forEach(p => {
      const rangeNotation = p.getRange().getA1Notation(); 
      const newRange = duplicatedSheet.getRange(rangeNotation); 
      const newProtection = newRange.protect().setDescription(p.getDescription()); 
      
      newProtection.setWarningOnly(p.isWarningOnly()); 
      if (!p.isWarningOnly()) { 
        newProtection.removeEditors(newProtection.getEditors()); 
        newProtection.addEditors(p.getEditors()); 
        // Copiar también los permisos de visualización si es necesario (opcional)
        newProtection.setDomainEdit(p.canDomainEdit());
      } 
    });

    // Pausar el script durante 1 segundo para evitar el timeout
    Utilities.sleep(3000);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error en la función duplicateSheetProtections:", error);
    // Manejar el error de timeout reintentando la operación después de un breve retraso
    Utilities.sleep(1000); // Esperar 1 segundo
    throw error; // Relanzar el error para que sea manejado por la función que llama a duplicateSheetProtections
  }
};


/*

const duplicateSheetProtections = (sheetName) => { 
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 

  const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(BASE_SHEET); 
  // Cambia esto por el nombre de tu hoja 
  const duplicatedSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName)
  duplicatedSheet.protect().remove();
  const protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE); 

  for (let i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) { 
    const p = protections[i]; 
    const rangeNotation = p.getRange().getA1Notation(); 
    const newRange = duplicatedSheet.getRange(rangeNotation); 
    const newProtection = newRange.protect().setDescription(p.getDescription()); 
    
    newProtection.setWarningOnly(p.isWarningOnly()); 
    if (!p.isWarningOnly()) { 
      newProtection.removeEditors(newProtection.getEditors()); 
      newProtection.addEditors(p.getEditors()); 
      // Copia también los permisos de visualización si es necesario (opcional) // 
      newProtection.setDomainEdit(p.canDomainEdit()); // Descomenta si es necesario } } }
    }
  }
}
*/
const trigger = () => {
  const spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('oli').timeBased().after(100).create()
}

const requiredPermissions = () => {
  ScriptApp.invalidateAuth()
  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
}


function onEdit(e) {  
  
  handleStudents()

  
}
```